# Writing a game in Java... how do I get from running a command line to a Windows .exe?

Tags: java, windows, installation

I realize this isn't specifically a Java programming question, but it *IS* about how to run specifically Java, so please don't make this off topic.

I'm working on a game, and I'm using Java as the programming language.

I'd like to be able to "package" what I've been working on into either a .zip file or a setup.exe or a .msi install package, so I can send it to my friends to try it out.

This is my question: How can I package a java based application for the common consumer, so that the end user only needs to install and run the game?

---

The Problem:

Running a java program requires a Java JRE to be installed. When I ask my friends to go to java.sun.com (oh, the good old days), they get redirected to Oracle, which gives about 150 links, NONE of them lead straight to the JRE. I have to click 2 links (if I know exactly what I'm looking for), and accept a license agreement longer that the longest filibuster in US history that I can't be bothered to read, and then they get to install the JRE, maybe, if their download servers don't bug out. Once that's done, they can open a command prompt, go to the directory where they've downloaded my game, and type:

javaw -Dcharset.UTF-8 -d64 -Xms2g -Xmx4g -jar %INSTALL_DIR%/bin/mygame.jar mygame.Main -c %USER_DIR%/config/config.xml

I can solve the problems above a developer, cause Eclipse manages half of it, and I know how to fix problems.

Most Windows installer creators I've seen are just plain terrible.

Is there an open source installer / patcher for Java Games? or something like that?

If not, who's up for making one :)

-Kai

---

PS: Again, I realize this isn't technically a Java programming question, BUT it is a question directly related to Java and OS compatibility, and it's a huge gap that simple googling doesn't answer. Mods, please don't class this offtopic: Java's nature as a programming language may make it OS independent, but distribution of a Java application in the real world is a real hurdle, enough that it makes it a problem for the language's future itself.

Comment: [Java Web Start](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml) might be start.  There are plenty of Windows "exe" wrappers about, [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) seems to be popular. [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) is a cross platform installer which might be of interest...If you want to go native on the MacOS, you might need to take a look at [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, but Java Web Start isn't what I'm looking for. I need 2GB plus of disk storage space and 2GB RAM space for the game to install and run, direct GPU access, the ability to run MySQL as a background process, etc. JWS is for tiny apps like Tetris. Launch4j is terribly restrictive... 

I'll look into IzPack and your link about MacOS. 

Thanks mate! =D